# Spring @Deletemapping : Could not resolve placeholder 'id' in value

Tags: spring, rest

I am pretty sure the response is on the site but I can't find it. What is **wrong** with this code in my @RestControler?

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteById/${id}")
public void deleteById(@PathVariable("id") Long id) {
    this.customerServiceImpl.deleteById(id);
}
```

**Error :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'id' in value "/deleteById/${id}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try it as. It should work.

```
@DeleteMapping("/deleteById/{id}")
public void deleteById(@PathVariable(name="id") Long id) {
    this.customerServiceImpl.deleteById(id);
}
```

Comment: I understood my mistake : never do copy/paste from Angular to Spring...!!! :o) Thanks!